# Hiding column of a gridview in visual webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spgridview

I am adding columns to `gridview` by following code..

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<Where><Eq>"
   + "<FieldRef Name='Filter' />"
   + "<Value Type='Integer'>1</Value>"
   + "</Eq></Where>";
```

What do I need to do if I have to hide the column but need to use the column data.

Answer (score 4):

- Bind the data to column in gridview, and set visibility property of that column to false
- Or you can hide using javascript

[similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392811/c-wpf-make-a-gridviewcolumn-visible-false)